# Twitter Bootstrap and Angular.js- Drop down Add to Tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

How add drop down to tab in angular.js and bootstarp here is my code

```
 <tabset class="nav nav-tabs centered-tab sub-nav">
    <tab heading="Bio"  class="dropdown-toggle" >
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
        <a>{{choice}}</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </tab>
 </tabset>
```

In controller

```
$scope.items = [
    "The first choice!",
    "And another choice for you.",
    "but wait! A third!"
  ];
```

Its not working when i clicked on "bio" tab

Comment: This example may help: http://www.bootply.com/62621

Comment: I have used this for dynamic tab but i want one of the tab will be dropdown menu . please can you help me?

Comment: @ShankarKamble you're using [`ui-bootstrap`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs)? As far as I can see, that library doesn't support dropdown-tabs.

Comment: @robertklep So Can you tell what should i used?

Comment: @ShankarKamble perhaps [`angular-strap`](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tab) supports it, but I'm not sure (also, [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/o3hSr8?p=preview) seems to implement it).

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggled with this myself and to spare anyone else the trouble of figuring out the solution, I'm posting this example (uses the Jade generator).

#### Requirements

- Angular Bootstrap setup

#### HTML

```
div(ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo")
 tabset(type="pills")
    tab
      tab-heading
         span.dropdown(on-toggle="toggled(open)" dropdown)
            a(href dropdown-toggle).dropdown-toggle 
              span Click me for a dropdown
            ul.dropdown-menu
               li
                  a(href) action
```

#### JavaScript

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

---

## Result:

[image]